# sql query to joint a data table with different data from another

Tags: mysql, sql

it is hard to explain and my english doesn't help, but there it is:
I have two data tables:  "nodes" and "records".
In the nodes table I save data of questions and data of answers

**nodes:**
| id | name  | type |

**records:**
| id | questionid | answerid |

I've tried albeit unsuccessfully, to make an sql query to gave me the data of all records but with the name of the answer and question intead of the id.
In short, what I need is:  records.id,  nodes.name (question) , nodes.name (answer)

Comment: There is not enough information. How nodes and records are related? Show some sample of your data.

Comment: records.questionid and records.answerid are related with the id from nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  questions.name AS questionname
  answers.name AS answername
FROM records
  INNER JOIN nodes AS questions ON records.questionid=questions.id
  INNER JOIN nodes AS answers ON records.answerid=answers.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT q.name AS question, a.name AS answer
FROM records r 
LEFT JOIN nodes q ON q.id = r.questionid
LEFT JOIN nodes a ON a.id = r.answerid
WHERE 1
```

For this query I build schema below:

```
CREATE TABLE nodes (
 id int auto_increment primary key, 
 name varchar(30),
 type int(1));

INSERT INTO nodes (name, type) VALUES
('Is it a question 01', 0),
('Is it a question 02', 0),
('This is an answer 01', 1),
('This is an answer 02', 1),
('This is an answer 03', 1);

CREATE TABLE records (
 id int auto_increment primary key, 
 questionid int(11),
 answerid int(11));

INSERT INTO records (questionid, answerid) VALUES
(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 4), (2, 5);
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfd340/1